# making a contingency table with TRUE and FALSE values

Tags: r, statistics, ggplot2, homework

I made the following contingency table already, however there should only be TRUE or FALSE and not all of them showing up on the table. How can I change that?
[image]

my code is the following:

```
library(tidyverse)
library(haven)
read_xpt("~/downloads/DEMO_J.XPT") -> demo17
demo17%>%
  select (subjectID= SEQN, Lebensalter=RIDAGEYR, Geschlecht=RIAGENDR, Ethnie = RIDRETH3, Einwohner=WTMEC2YR, Ratio=INDFMPIR)%>%
  mutate(Geschlecht=fct_recode(factor(Geschlecht), "Männlich"="1", "Weiblich"="2"))%>%
  mutate(Ethnie=fct_recode(factor (Ethnie), "Mexican American"="1", "Other Hispanic"="2", "NH White"="3", "NH Black"="4", "NH Asian"="6", "Other"="7")) -> D2


read_xpt("~/downloads/BMX_J.XPT") -> bmx17

bmx17%>%
  select (subjectID = SEQN, Körpergröße= BMXHT, Gewicht = BMXWT) -> B2

inner_join(D2, B2, by= "subjectID") -> DurchgangJ
DurchgangJ

DurchgangJ%>%
  mutate( bmi = Gewicht / (Körpergröße/100)^2 ) %>%
  filter( Lebensalter >= 18 )%>%
  filter(!is.na(bmi))%>%
  mutate (Adipös= bmi>=30)%>%
  mutate (Poor = Ratio < 1.3)%>%
  filter(!is.na(Poor))%>%
  ggplot+
  geom_point(aes(x= Poor, y= Adipös))+
  facet_grid(Ethnie~Geschlecht)
```

The table used for the plot looks like this:
[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's normal that you have both TRUE and FALSE everywhere since you use these values as coordinates. This means that for every individual who has for instance TRUE as X and FALSE as Y, a point is added for x=TRUE and Y=FALSE.

- Since there are many individuals with TRUE as X and FALSE as Y in your data, the points are just plotted on top of each and you see a single point.
- Since there is at least one individual with every combination of TRUE/FALSE for X and for Y in the data, there are points everywhere.

So your plot is not meaningful because for every facet combination it shows only TRUE or FALSE as coordinates. A more meaningful plot would show the *distribution* for each case of the two variables, and this can be done with `geom_histogram`. For a single variable something like this should work:

```
ggplot+
  geom_histogram(aes(x= Poor))+
  facet_grid(Ethnie~Geschlecht)
```

You can show the two variables either as an additional facet or as colours, but you need to format the data differently: there should be a single column `value` for the TRUE/FALSE value and another column `category` indicating whether this is the `Poor` or `Adipös` value (i.e. two rows for every individual). It's certainly doable with `tidyverse` but I don't use it so I don't know how (I use `melt` for this). Then you could do this for instance:

```
ggplot+
  geom_histogram(aes(x= value, fill=category),alpha=.5)+
  facet_grid(Ethnie~Geschlecht)
```

Note that a contingency table is not a graph, it's a table with numbers.

Comment: Thank you very much that has helped a lot. I now did `ggplot+
  geom_histogram(aes( y= Poor, fill=Adipös), stat = "count")+
  facet_grid(Ethnie~Geschlecht)` and got a much better graph.